# Is Linq2Entities faster than storedProc with multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, linq

QI have inherited several stored procedure calls to MSSql.  This one contains several joins.  My question is: would using L2E be faster in this case than calling the stored procedure directly via ADO?  Here is my LinQ query:

```
   public List<object> getDNISData(int DNIS)
    {
        List<object> DataItems = new List<object>();
        using (VPEntities VPCtx = new VPEntities())
        {
            var DD = 
                from nm in VPCtx.NumberMaps
                join g in VPCtx.Greetings on nm.Greeting_ID equals g.Greeting_ID
                join p1 in VPCtx.Prompts on nm.Prompt1_ID equals p1.Prompt_ID
                join p2 in VPCtx.Prompts on nm.Prompt2_ID equals p2.Prompt_ID
                join p3 in VPCtx.Prompts on nm.Prompt3_ID equals p3.Prompt_ID
                join p4 in VPCtx.Prompts on nm.Prompt4_ID equals p4.Prompt_ID
                join p5 in VPCtx.Prompts on nm.Prompt5_ID equals p5.Prompt_ID
                join h1 in VPCtx.HoldMsgs on nm.HoldMsg1_ID equals h1.HoldMsg_ID
                join h2 in VPCtx.HoldMsgs on nm.HoldMsg2_ID equals h2.HoldMsg_ID
                join hm in VPCtx.HoldMusics on nm.HoldMusic_ID equals hm.HoldMusic_ID
                join d in VPCtx.Disclaimers on nm.Disclaimer_ID equals d.Disclaimer_ID
                where nm.DNIS == DNIS && nm.Enabled 
                select (new {NumberID = nm.Number_ID, PortfolioID = nm.Portfolio_ID, PropertyID = nm.Property_ID, Adsource = nm.AdSource_ID,
                                    PlanTypeID = nm.PlanType_ID, GreetingFile = g.GreetingFile,  
                                    PromptFile1 = p1.PromptFile,  Accepts1 = p1.Accepts, PromptAction_ID1 = p1.PromptAction_ID,  
                                    PromptFile2 = p2.PromptFile,  Accepts2 = p2.Accepts, PromptAction_ID2 = p2.PromptAction_ID, 
                                    PromptFile3 = p3.PromptFile, Accepts3 = p3.Accepts, PromptAction_ID3 = p3.PromptAction_ID,
                                    PromptFile4 = p4.PromptFile, Accepts4 = p4.Accepts, PromptAction_ID4 = p4.PromptAction_ID, 
                                    PromptFile5 = p5.PromptFile, Accepts5 = p5.Accepts, PromptAction_ID5 = p5.PromptAction_ID,
                                    HoldMsgFile1 = h1.HoldMsgFile, HoldMsgFile2 = h2.HoldMsgFile,
                                    Destination1 = nm.Destination1, Destination2 = nm.Destination2, Destination3 = nm.Destination3,
                                    UIType_ID = nm.UIType_ID,
                                    RingCount = nm.RingCount,
                                    Enabled = nm.Enabled,
                                    Spanish = nm.Spanish,
                                    HoldMusicFile = hm.HoldMusicFile,
                                    Template_ID = nm.Template_ID,
                                    FrontLineForward = nm.FrontLineForward,
                                    DisclaimerFIle = d.DisclaimerFile});
           DataItems = DD.ToList<object>();

            return DataItems;
        };
    }
```

Comment: Look at the generated query through profiler, compare execution plan of generated query with that of proc, only then you can know. There is no way for us to know that.

Comment: this is why linq sometimes go too far, love TSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the LINQ query there is a direct translation of the SQL query contained in the stored procedure, it will probably be slightly faster to invoke the stored procedure--not because it would impact performance on the database, but because LINQ to Entities has to translate your query to SQL first.

The cost of that translation is going to be the same regardless of the size of your data, though, so the difference will probably only be noticeable if the query runs very quickly on the database, but you're invoking it many, many times. Until you notice performance being a problem, I'd recommend doing whatever makes your code easiest to maintain.